# Samsung Galaxy S8 navigation bar overlays fixed position div

Tags: android, css, ios7

I have  this HTML:

```
<div class="app-bar">
    <a href="#'>icon</a>
    <a href="#'>icon</a>
    <a href="#'>icon</a>
    <a href="#'>icon</a>
</div>'''
```

With the following CSS:

```
.app-bar {
     position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This code  is working great for me, but the digital navigation bar on phones such as a Galaxy S8 currently overlay the fixed position links; causing the links to get cut off about halfway from the bottom. How can I ensure the fixed position links only show above a phones navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to calculate the height of the nav-bar of the phone. add the height to the bottom css. Like if the height is 20px, then you can add this css below.

```css
.app-bar {
     position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that each device has a specific height navigation bar and others have no navigation bar at all, so with this CSS it's going to raise it 20px regardless of if the device has a 20px navigation bar or not. I know it can be done with JS, but I was hoping I didn't have to take that route and could stick with CSS somehow.

Comment: Maybe it can't be done CSS only. Lets hope someone can have answer for that.